# How to use v-flex auto , fixed size card and card arrangement?

Tags: vuetify.js

I wanted to make my card responsive to all kind of screen size which the arrangement of the card will follow the size of screen. I have problem which after changing from `<v-flex xs6 md2>` to `<v-flex auto>` and the card arrangement are different.

I have tried to use shrink but the problem still the same. I change the height of the card to be 100% height and the problem are still the same.

```
 <v-layout row wrap>

        <v-flex auto class="px-2" v-for="n in 11"
              :key="n">
           <v-card>
            <v-img
          height="100%"
          width="100%"
          src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1592/5969/products/mc18_149_m10-trinity_knot_ring_a.jpg?v=1539363759"
        ></v-img>
            <v-card-title > <h4 class="text-md-center">Barang Kemas Termurah</h4></v-card-title>
            <v-card-text >
            <table style="width:100%">



              <tr class="font-weight-small">
                <td>Item Code</td>
                <td >SKT1123</td>
              </tr>
               <tr class="font-weight-small">
                <td>Approx. Weight</td>
                <td>2.37 g</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><v-divider></v-divider></td><br>
            </tr>
               <tr class="font-weight-medium">
                <td>Price Range</td>
                <td>RM300-2300</td>
              </tr>

              <tr class="green--text font-weight-medium">
                <td >Stock Available</td>
                <td>30</td>

              </tr>
            </table>
            </v-card-text>

              <v-card-actions>
           <v-btn block color="secondary" dark>ORDER</v-btn>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                  <v-btn icon>
                    <v-icon>favorite</v-icon>
                  </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>




          </v-card>
        </v-flex>

      </v-layout>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/81w97ly2ml?fontsize=14 < - Here the code sample from the codesandbox .

I want the card to appear in same size for all card same like eCommerce product card responsive to the screen size changes. Which mean the size of card remain fixed when the screen size change.